# Sound not working on Gigabyte X-99 Internal Audio

Tags: sound, 15.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I am using a Chillblast Fusion Ares X99 desktop, with a Gigabyte GA-X99-Gaming 5 Intel X99 motherboard, using the "Onboard High Definition Audio". The sound works with no problems in Windows 7, but no sound for Ubuntu 15.04 (including the drum beats prior to log-in), for either speakers or headphones. Uninstalling and reinstalling alsa-base and pulseaudio make no difference.

There is no obvious problem from alsamixer (i.e. nothing muted), and pavucontrol recognises when I play music. I ran the Ubuntu "System Testing", and it gave the following output for "suspend/audio_before_suspend":

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/nest-wq0rkm8o.53da2f0d5daa59cf2d6aa81031bd900071c971e89e30e8d5dd45c710404c5805/audio_settings", line 9, in <module> sys.exit(main()) File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/checkbox_support/scripts/audio_settings.py", line 355, in main store_audio_settings(args.file) File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/checkbox_support/scripts/audio_settings.py", line 213, in store_audio_settings default = default_regex.search(pactl_status).group() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Similarly, the output for "audio/playback_headphones" was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/nest-td8cf36w.643e5ad0812fcf48d57b503acb6e3791032f1d12d63236f936b818ff72d7a276/audio_settings", line 9, in <module> sys.exit(main()) File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/checkbox_support/scripts/audio_settings.py", line 355, in main store_audio_settings(args.file) File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/checkbox_support/scripts/audio_settings.py", line 213, in store_audio_settings default = default_regex.search(pactl_status).group() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' Attempting to initialize Gstreamer pipeline: audiotestsrc wave=sine freq=512 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink Pipeline initialized, now starting playback. ERROR:root:Unable to restore settings because settings file is invalid
```

And the output for "audio/playback_auto" was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/nest-2mdgbmu7.c0275b29d727bcbab35c795ee540f8c7c7387b66c402d24f74b7ebb75fa18270/audio_settings", line 9, in <module> sys.exit(main()) File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/checkbox_support/scripts/audio_settings.py", line 355, in main store_audio_settings(args.file) File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/checkbox_support/scripts/audio_settings.py", line 213, in store_audio_settings default = default_regex.search(pactl_status).group() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' Attempting to initialize Gstreamer pipeline: audiotestsrc wave=sine freq=512 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink Pipeline initialized, now starting playback. ERROR:root:Unable to restore settings because settings file is invalid
```

I'm afraid my adventures down the rabbit hole of soundcards didn't lead me anywhere productive, and I don't know how best to go about troubleshooting this problem. Any tips and advice would be gratefully received.

Comment: I think I've made some progress (but still haven't fixed it) - it seems that Ubuntu is recognising the HMDI and S/PDIF outputs, but not the analogue output that I'm actually using. Curiously, it does recognise the headphones when I plug them into the front-facing jack, but no sound comes out of those either.

Comment: I took a look in Windows, and apparently the sound driver is a Sound Blaster Recon 3Di from Creative Technology Ltd.. However, the PC was supplied using "Onboard High Definition Audio" rather than a separate sound card.

Adding the lines
`rmmod snd_hda_intel
modprobe snd_hda_intel position_fix=1`
to `/etc/rc.local` makes no difference